# Microsoft Excel 2010 Search for Specific Text and copy it to new cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of single words in a column A1:A10.
In row A11:G11 I have words which could include a word from the list. If it does it could be the only word or appear together with another word in that cell (space in between). In cell G12 I want the word listed in the column and appearing in the row be replicated. Extremely thankful for all help.

Comment: So what have you tried already? Where are you stuck with it?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, please read [ask] and edit your question to include what you've tried and what research you've already done. As it stands, this question shows little effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your question however you will need to move the data in a11 to the right 1 cell for this to work.

put the following formula in cells B1:F10

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($11:$11,$A:$A)),$11:$11&" ","")

Put the following formula in cells H1:H10

=CONCATENATE($B:$B,$C:$C,$D:$D,$E:$E,$F:$F,$G:$G)

Comment: Can you please (1) explain more clearly what you mean when you say "Put the following formula into the following ***cells***", (2) explain how this is supposed to work, and (3) post a screenshot showing that you actually got it to work?